# Python virtual environments do nothing

Tags: virtualenv, python-venv, virtual-environment

I've recently tried to start using virtual environments but I cannot get them to work as they should.

When I activate a virtual environment, my python interpreter seems to ignore it completely, and continue using my global environment. It says that the packages that I've installed to my virtual environment do not exist and it continues to use my global packages. I've tried using virtualenv and venv and they both have the same problem. Am I supposed to have my project files in a certain location with respect to the virtual environment folder?

FYI, I am using Windows 10

Comment: Are you activating your environment using `source`? For example, `source env/bin/activate`

Comment: Yes. Like: source env/Scripts/activate

Comment: If I am not mistaken, on Windows you should not need the `source` part. Just execute the `env/bin/activate.bat` script instead.

Comment: I think you need to use source in Git bash. I went ahead and tried activating it with that command in Powershell but it made no difference. I'm curious if my interpreter has to change its path to use a virtual environment?

Answer (score 0):

My virtual environment was also using my global environment only (using system site programs and packages; Windows 10). I used commands `virtualenv .env -p python3` and `.env\Scripts\activate`. I found out there is a problem with paths (`%PATH%`). VEnv was in `echo %PATH%` but when I tried `where python` or `where pip`, path for VEnv was not there. I had very long length and diacritics in my path. I moved the project to a new directory (short simple path), generated a new virtual environment, activated and eureka. Virtual environment works.